# Facebook authentication error in Kohana

Tags: facebook, authentication, kohana

i have problem when i try to make Facebook authentication in Kohana.

What i do is:

In kohana i have view file called loginview.php where i have embedded this code

```
href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=341106515944015"&redirect_uri=http://verana.ge/fbauth/&scope=user_about_me&state=veranalast">
```

and in controller folder i have controller called fbauth.php where i have this code

```
 public function action_index()
{

   $app_id = "341106515944015";
   $app_secret = "79f547b92f34f886cc8d51ca1a5d33e0";
   $my_url = "http://verana.ge/";

  // session_start(); <!-- commented because in Kohana the Session is already started -->

   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
   $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
         $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
     . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
     . $_SESSION['state'];
   echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    }

if($_REQUEST["state"] = 'veranalast') {
   $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;


   $response = file_get_contents($token_url);

   $params = null;

   parse_str($response, $params);


   $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
             . $params['access_token'];

   $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
           echo("Hello " . $user->name);
}
else {
   echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
}


}
```

but when i hit on facebook link and trying to connect i getting the error which says the following

```
  ErrorException [ Warning ]: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=341106515944015&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fverana.ge%2F&client_secret=79f547b92f34f886cc8d51ca1a5d33e0&code=AQB9jQDcWXNVhPoxhOH-GyJ_0P0UQD9y5wfFy8cfP48TxvlX0VnycEWSpTOC0NWXTyCfssTUHCwFjmZdySy74zor_AQGvtzE5YCkB3asMBhWiiAJhesbFa_GrQIzT7UWiNrbl73CmVz5hell-shwrnavUviuDvpMqg6jCbMBHa6nb39xvidf-P5KOe4wlyR9TG8) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad APPPATH/classes/controller/fbauth.php [ 32 ]
27             $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
28             . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
29             . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;
30 
31             
32             $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
33             
34             $params = null;
35                         
36             parse_str($response, $params);
37
```

also for double check i created this function outside Kohana and it worked without problem.

what i did was that out side Kohana i created file named by index.php where i putted html a tag of
  Facebook authentication and next i created file named by testauth.php  in which i putted as same
  code as i putted in fbauth.php and as i said it worked without problem.

may be where are simple way to figured it out but i don't know it. Please tell me how to fix it.

Any Ides?

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=341106515944015&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fverana.ge%2F&client_secret=79f547b92f34f886cc8d51ca1a5d33e0&code=AQB9jQDcWXNVhPoxhOH-GyJ_0P0UQD9y5wfFy8cfP48TxvlX0VnycEWSpTOC0NWXTyCfssTUHCwFjmZdySy74zor_AQGvtzE5YCkB3asMBhWiiAJhesbFa_GrQIzT7UWiNrbl73CmVz5hell-shwrnavUviuDvpMqg6jCbMBHa6nb39xvidf-P5KOe4wlyR9TG8` ? It produces 400 HTTP error. Everything is ok.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  This error does not appear when i do Facebook authentication from out side Kohana on same host with same codes and i cannot find the reason why it is happening in Kohana.

Comment: If I go to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=341106515944015&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fverana.ge%2F&client_secret=79f547b92f34f886cc8d51ca1a5d33e0&code=AQB9jQDcWXNVhPoxhOH-GyJ_0P0UQD9y5wfFy8cfP48TxvlX0VnycEWSpTOC0NWXTyCfssTUHCwFjmZdySy74zor_AQGvtzE5YCkB3asMBhWiiAJhesbFa_GrQIzT7UWiNrbl73CmVz5hell-shwrnavUviuDvpMqg6jCbMBHa6nb39xvidf-P5KOe4wlyR9TG8` myself I see OAuth exception. Maybe you should use PHP OAuth library `http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php` but not just `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: I found reason so i replaced the code $_REQUEST['code']  in fbauth.php with if(isset($_REQUEST['code'])) $code = $_REQUEST["code"]; and know it is working well.